# New tire tube and grinding noise?

Tags: repair, derailleur-rear, noise

I punctured my tire tube so i had to remove my back wheel out and replaced the tube, when reassembled, derailleurs started making grinding noises.
I checked where the sound was coming and it was definitely from there, not the wheel, it only made the sounds when i switch to low gear. It makes sounds even when im not on it just turning it, its barely a month old so i dont think its the chain, was i putting it back the wrong way?

Comment: Welcome to the site - it sounds like the chain has ended up in the wrong place, somehow.  Could you add a photo of that area of the bike, with [edit] ?

Comment: Another possibility is that you have a horizontal rear dropout and the wheel is not properly aligned.